# How do I prevent Chrome Canary from updating -OR- How do I sync two Chrome profiles with the same account?

Tags: google-chrome, sync, google-chrome-extensions, bookmarks, google-accounts

I might have a bit an unusual request, but my situation is as follows:

- I have a low-end pc, which means, I need to be careful about performance
- This is why I need to deactivate automatic updates in Chrome
- I also need to use Chrome in two versions (both of them syncing bookmarks with my Google account): with and without extensions (however, in both versions I want to be logged in, so I cannot use the Incognito mode for the no-extensions version)

---

I already tried:

- Using Incognito mode for the no-extensions version, but there I'm not logged in by default
- Using Chrome profiles, but I somehow cannot sync two profiles with the same account...
- Using Chrome and Chrome Canary, but I failed to deactivate automatic update for Canary...

**Is there a way to use Chrome parallel with and without extensions, while having the bookmarks always in sync with the Google account?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm. Just found out Google doesn't allow you to have multiple profiles with the same email for some reason. Anyway, there's always a workaround. Here's one that involves creating a new profile independent of your default one:

- Create a new shortcut to `chrome.exe` (or just copy-paste an existing one), place it on the desktop and name it whatever you want.
- Right-click it, click `Properties` and go to the `Shortcuts` tab.
- In the `Target` box, at the end, insert a <kbd>space</kbd>, followed by `--user-data-dir="C:\path\to\dir"` where `path\to\dir` is the folder where you want to store your profile. Eg:

> "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --user-data-dir="C:\Chrome\Profile1"

Now just double-click your shortcut, sign-in and follow [Garrett's](https://superuser.com/a/738914/161391) instructions to selectively sync only what you want.

---

Or instead of having 2 separate Chrome profiles, you could just create a second shortcut that has extensions disabled. Same as before, just create a shortcut to chrome.exe and in the target box insert `--disable-extensions` at the end. Although, you can't have this chrome open alongside the main window. It's either one or the other.

[Here's](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) a bunch of command line options for Chrome that you can checkout.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed. However, using the first method with creating a new profile, I had the problem, that when I start the shortcut, Chrome opens and downloads "chrome.exe"... Maybe this is because I left the folder for the new profile empty?

Comment: Method 2 with disabling extensions works fine, there is the slight disadvantage that I cannot run both versions of Chrome together. But I think I could arrange myself with that.

Comment: @Cyman that means you have entered chrome.exe twice which is causing chrome to open and navigate to the second chrome.exe, which triggers the download. Make sure you have it in the same format I've given above. The new profile folder _should_ ideally be empty, chrome will auto populate it.

Comment: Great, the method with the profile worked now. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome, hit the 3 horizontal lines button in the top right (the thing that replaced the wrench icon) and go to `Settings`.  At the top where you are signed in, select `Advanced sync settings...`.  Switch from `Sync everything` to `Choose what to sync` and select only the things you want to sync across your browsers.

Comment: OK, this actually I've already done. But how can I run "another" Chrome version/installation now on the same PC where I have different extensions running?

Comment: @Cyman is the problem installing a second copy of Chrome or getting different extensions to run in the second copy?

Comment: OK, if you put it this way, the problem is installing a second copy of Chrome, actually.

Comment: @Cyman Chrome will not allow multiple copies to be installed on the same computer unless one of them is Canary and the other is either the public release or the dev version.

Comment: OK, thank you. I figured out, that I cannot disable updates for Canary, but can I disable auto-updating for Chrome Dev?

Comment: @Cyman You can check out how to disable the auto-updating [here](http://www.chromium.org/administrators/turning-off-auto-updates), though I'm not sure why you would want to.