# Run 2 multiple chrome process instances with different executable filename; not working

Tags: windows, google-chrome, multiple-instances

I'm using VirtuaWin and it lets you assign different desktops to different processes, and I want to assign 2 different chrome processes to 2 different desktops.

So I tried to copy and rename a `chrome.exe` process to `chrome2.exe` and run it. But running either of them only opens a new sub-process under the already running previous process. So running `chrome.exe` and then `chrome2.exe` will not open a new `chrome2.exe` but only another `chrome.exe`.

Is there a way to run the two processes under their own different executable namespace?

Comment: Have you tried using different chrome profiles: [pic](http://cdn2.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/chrome-profiles-header.png)

Comment: @Cybertox doesn't work either. They too open in the same older process.

Comment: You should try the first solution in [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/739345/161391) to create a new profile.

Comment: @Cybertox I was already doing that, I use profiles extensively. Doesn't work. :/

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to run **separate instances** of **Chrome**. However, by using this method, all separate instances of **Chrome** still run under one and the same namespace **chrome.exe**.

Maybe it would be possible to edit portable versions of Google Chrome to run under different namespace by using **Windows Resource editors**, such as **Resource Hacker** or **Resource Tuner**?

The method described below achieves to run **Google Chrome** in totally separate instances. If you managed to edit one instance to have a different namespace through resource editor, you may achieve your goal. Here's how to run multiple instances of **Chrome**:

As of 2014-10-05, the easiest way to run multiple versions or instances of Chrome is to use Google Chrome Portable, downloaded from:
http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/google_chrome_portable

Currently I'm running 4 separate instances of Google Chrome v37.0.2062.124. One instance is installed and three other instances of Google Chrome are portable.

Here's how my Windows 7 Taskbar looks like when all 4 instances of Chrome are opened:

[image: 4 separate instances of Chrome]

If you want to change Google Chrome icon that is shown on the Windows Taskbar once Google Chrome is started, then you should follow this link:
[Is it possible to customize taskbar icons? If so how?](https://superuser.com/questions/613851/is-it-possible-to-customize-taskbar-icons-if-so-how)

The answer is given in comments: you need to change icons that are stored in chrome.dll using Resource Tuner (use Trial version) or Resource Hacker (free).

My answer doesn't show exactly how to run multiple instances of **Chrome** with different executable filename (as you requested), but I hope it could lead you into the right direction.

**Good luck!**

Answer (score 0):

chrome.exe --new-window https://url/etc

If it's for a dashboard monitor so u want each browser window in full-screen mode (no addr/status/tool bars), also add a --start-fullscreen to each chrome cmd line